# Saturation gradual spread - post-processing

Tags: unity-game-engine, grayscale, post-processing

I want to make a saturation effect that slowly spreads across the screen using post-processing. I've managed to make the entire scene saturate, but I am not able to figure out any way to make it spread from a small point. Is there anyone that knows if this is possible, and if it is, how?

I was thinking of making it local and having a blend distance, but this doesn't do anything.

Thanks.

Comment: is this a shader you are writing?

Comment: No, I was trying to write a shader. But when I tried applying the shader on seperate objects, it stopped working. I still want to figure out how shading works, but I've got a deadline that makes it difficult for me to invest so much time.